# Error in default 'Principled BSDF' material

Tags: rendering, materials, blender-internal-render-engine

Pls refer to the attached screengrab of default material tab.
Principled BSDF don't look white.
And when i render the default cube, it's purple.
Tried loading factory defalut settings too.
Pls help.
[image: Default shader in Material Tab]
[image: Default Cube rendered]

Comment: Do you have a texture connected to the *Principled BSDF* node?

Comment: No. It's jus the default cube.

Comment: Purple normally means missing textures files, can you post the .blend? https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: Posted the blend file "OrbitalStall.blend" in this link. [<img src="https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/embedImage.png?bid=6469" />](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/6469/)
I noticed the purple color material was only on eevee. In cycles, it renders as expected.